# Does git cause Windows 10 Explorer to hang with 100% one-core usage, usually inside zip files, since the Dec 2021 update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze, zip, cpu-usage

Since the Dec 2021 monthly update on *two different machines* with Windows 10 I have seen the same behavior: entering a zip file file from Explorer results in 100% one-CPU-core usage that persists until explorer is force crashed.

It seems not to matter too much what zip file I enter. They are mostly from github for stuff I don't care to git clone, i.e. obtained with "download as zip". In any case, even if the zip files are malformed somehow, it's not reasonable program behavior to hang on them.

The workaround, besides being careful no to enter any zip files, is of course to just crash explorer from Task Manager and restart it (File > Run New Task, type "explorer"). I suppose one can also disable "zip folders", although I don't remember how that's done. (Perhaps the method described [here](https://superuser.com/a/59346/345617) for doing the latter in Win 7 still works in Win 10. Given that Microsoft appears to have changed the register details for that and consequently the necessary procedure across OS major releases, I'm not 100% confident on that.)

Has anyone else experienced this behavior of Explorer hanging in zips after the Dec 2021 update? Is it a known bug that's tracked by Microsoft somewhere?

As helpfully noticed in a comment below, this doesn't to other people. After a bit more investigation, here's the interesting bit: if I have recently rebooted the machine even if Explorer goes into a zip, nothing bad happens. But as soon as I type a git command, the Explorer that was ok in a zip until then, goes to 100% CPU on one thread. So there's some kind of strange interaction with git's experimental file monitor on Windows.

Yeah, it's definitely `git` causing this. It even does it without the Explorer being in any zip file, just regular directories, although in those circumstances the Explorer livelock happens much less often, but it's always triggered by some unrelated git command. Using `git version 2.34.1.windows.1` if anybody cares.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce on any of my 21H2 machines.  You should look towards what third-party software is common across your machines.

Comment: @Ramhound: thanks for the sanity check. I have a feeling it might be git's file system monitor doing this then. Because I don't really have anything else installed that might qualify for such interaction.